# Unable to get CPU usage information on Mac since CPU Cores is sometimes reported as 0

Tags: php, laravel, macos, cpu

I have the below function trying to retrieve CPU usage on Mac:

```
public function getCPUUsage()
{
        $cpuload = (float)exec("ps -A -o %cpu | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'");
        $cpu_cores = (int)exec("sysctl -a | grep 'machdep.cpu.core_count' | awk '{print $2}'");
        return $cpuload / $cpu_cores;
}
```

When I call it in tinker, it works:

```
vpn-self-service mathewparet$ php artisan tinker
usePsy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.3.11 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> use SystemInfo;
>>> SystemInfo::getCPUUsage();
=> 9.6
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye
vpn-self-service mathewparet$
```

But when the same is called in a controller it cpu_cores are returned as 0

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SystemInfo;

class SystemStatusController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $cpu = SystemInfo::getCPUUsage();
        
        return compact('cpu');
    }
}
```

The same method is called in tinker as well as on the controller. But when calling via tinker cpu cores are > 0 (which is what I expect) but when doing the same on the controller cpu cores are returned as 0 causing the next statement in `getCPUUsage()` to fail with division by zero.

Comment: It's because the webserver user (probably `www-data`) does not have the rights to execute the command. To prove it, you can create a minimal testing PHP script with the `getCPUUsage()` contents only and run it in a browser.

Comment: I use Laravel Valet to run the website. Both Valet and Tinker runs as the same user.

Comment: I just ran ```posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];``` to see which user the script is being called as.  Both in tinker and webserver is being called as my own user account.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it done using python.

```
$cpu_cores = (int)exec("python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print(mp.cpu_count())'");
```